# TFS Build Website deployment package web.config transformation not working

Tags: web-config, transformation

So I am trying to use TFS Build for generating deployment packages for my 3 environments (ST, UAT, Prod). 
This what I followed to successfully genrate the package locally.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/74bb16ab-5fe6-4c00-951b-666afd639864/

So my local machine will generate the package for the acyive configuration and everything is good. Here is my Build definition :
/p:DeployOnBuild=true;DeployTarget=Package
I run my solution file and the web deployment project in the Projects To Build.

It creates the respective folders with ST, UAT and PROD. In each of these there is a _PublishedWebsites folder. This folder have 2 folders.

1) MydeploymentProject - It contains the transformed web.config
2) MyDeploymentProject_Package - Contains the Package folder contents along with the zip file and setparameters files. Here the everything is not transformed. But if I check the TempBuildDir on the TFS server it does contain the transformed config.

When compared the logs local and on server, I found that the on my local After transformation files are updated and package is created whereas on TFS the AfterBuild target is called transformation done and it ends there.

this is my local log
Target "WPPCopyWebApplicaitonPipelineCircularDependencyError" skipped, due to false condition; ($(WPPCopyWebApplicaitonPipelineCircularDependencyError)) was evaluated as (False).
Target "ProcessItemToExcludeFromDeployment" in file "C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets" from project "C:\TAX-IT\Main\Source\TDDB\TDDB_deploy2\TDDB_deploy2.wdproj" (target "PipelineCollectFilesPhase" depends on it):
Done building target "ProcessItemToExcludeFromDeployment" in project "TDDB_deploy2.wdproj".
Target "GetProjectWebProperties" in file "C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets" from project "C:\TAX-IT\Main\Source\TDDB\TDDB_deploy2\TDDB_deploy2.wdproj" (target "PipelineCollectFilesPhase" depends on it):
Using "GetProjectProperties" task from assembly "C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\WebDeployment\v10.0\....\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll".
Task "GetProjectProperties"

I am not sure what is wrong.
Also I installed VS2010, web deploy 2.0 and 3.0 and web deployment tools on my Build servers.

Anyone have faced this and resolved.
Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

MadCoder,

From what I've gathered from your description, you have everything set up correctly. It seems like you are just missing the "Configuration" parameter. When you do run the Build Definition, it uses the configuration specified in your "Configurations to Build" argument. If you want to have multiple configurations built (like you are suggesting), you'll need to have multiple configurations defined. One question I have is: When you look at the logs of the TFS Build Process, do you see multiple configurations built, or do you only see one? If you only see one, then you don't have all of the configurations defined in order to transform the config file. According to your description, you'll need to see something like this in your build definition configuration:

[image]

If you don't want to deploy to a webserver, you can stop reading here, and don't have to continue on.

---

If you choose to use a TFS Build Definition to deploy to a web server, you'll need to have a target web server somewhere and you'll need to install and configure the Web Deploy v2/v3 on that server as well.

When you are using TFS Build Definitions to deploy, the transformation happens upon deployment, not during packaging (prior to deployment). It may package up a transformed config somewhere, but it won't actually transform the config bundled with the website. The only way I've been able to get the deployment to actually work with a transformed config is when I had a website specified in the MSBUILD args. Here is an example of my MSBUILD args:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=RemoteAgent /p:MsDeployServiceUrl=MyWebServer/MsDeployAgentService /p:DeployIisAppPath="MyWebsite as named in IIS"  /p:UserName=MyDomain\MyWebDeployUser /p:Password=MyWebDeployPassword
```

If you don't want MSBUILD to do the actual deployment (I prefer not to because then your deployment process is tied to TFS), you can do the deployment after the build process and use [the CTT Project, found on codeplex](http://ctt.codeplex.com). This tool performs the exact same transformations as MSBUILD, but it also includes the ability to parameterize settings so you can define classes of environments (for example, 3 QA environments, 2 Staging Environments, etc.) and still use the respective transforms for that class of environment.

Comment: Thanks jarrettcoggin. I have specified the 3 configurations. So it  created the appropriate folders(ST, UAT, PROD) with transformed web.configs in the drop folder (where entire website) is present and a package folder with setParamters.xml having development configuration settings and zip file containing untransformed web.config. When I do "Build Deployment Package" on my local the package has the setParameters.xml having the respective environement connection string settings. I checked everything from installations on my machine to access rights on folders. It just doesnot work